# How to center list of links in a straight line. CSS

Tags: html, css, web

**Hello!**

I have been trying for some time now, searching the net but with no hope. 
I am trying to align these links in a straight line in the center of the screen using CSS. However, I have not managed to do so... Answers are appreciated. :-)

Kind regards
Christoffer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WikiPeople</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">

</head>
<body bgcolor="black">

<br />
<br />
<br />

<a href="a-z.html"> A-D </a>
<a href="a-z.html"> E-H </a>
<a href="a-z.html"> I-L </a>
<a href="a-z.html"> M-Q </a>
<a href="a-z.html"> R-U </a>
<a href="a-z.html"> V-Z</a>
</body>
</html>



p {
color: red;
font-family: Times;
font-size: 15px;
}
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
color: red;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
color: red;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
   color: hotpink;
 }

/* selected link */
a:active {
color: blue;
}
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
background-color: #f44336;
color: white;
padding: 14px 25px;
text-align: center; 
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
border: none;
outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

put the links in an unordered list (`ul`) and assign `display: inline-block`  to the `li` elements. Wrap the ul in a div to which you assign `text-align: center;`:

```
<div class="x">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link_1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link_2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link_3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.x {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  width: auto;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaOWrm

Comment: It moved it a little bit, but not  quite to the center of the screen. Do I need to create borders or how so?

Comment: Yeah now I see it thanks for your time in helping me :)

Comment: Sorry, kinda  new, didn't see the tic :P

Answer (score 0):

I will give you my answer

**HTML**

```
<body bgcolor="black">

<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="center">
<a href="a-z.html"> A-D </a>
<a href="a-z.html"> E-H </a>
<a href="a-z.html"> I-L </a>
<a href="a-z.html"> M-Q </a>
<a href="a-z.html"> R-U </a>
<a href="a-z.html"> V-Z</a>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
color: red;
font-family: Times;
font-size: 15px;
}
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
color: red;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
color: red;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
   color: hotpink;
 }

/* selected link */
a:active {
color: blue;
}
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
background-color: #f44336;
color: white;
padding: 14px 25px;
text-align: center; 
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
border: none;
outline: none;
}
.center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Changes
- I added the links into a div
- I added a class named center

**DEMO**

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/DlanorJQ/4tp8gyjy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue, by following Johannes advice and then adding the center tags

Code looks like so:

```
 <center>
<ul>
<li><a href="a-z.html"> A-D </a></li>
<li><a href="e-h.html"> E-H </a></li>
<li><a href="i-l.html"> I-L </a></li>
<li><a href="m-q.html"> M-Q </a></li>
<li><a href="r-u.html"> R-U </a></li>
<li><a href="v-z.html"> V-Z</a></li>
</ul>
</center>


li {
display: inline-block;
}
```